# Eq. 45-46 in Gibbs Sampling for the Uninitiated

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, natural-language, gibbs

I am trying to figure out how Eq. 45 simplifies to Eq. 46 in the paper - "Gibbs Sampling for the Uninitiated" by Resnik and Hardisty.[www.cs.umd.edu/~hardisty/papers/gsfu.pdf](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~hardisty/papers/gsfu.pdf) (page 15)

Eq. 45

$$ \frac{\Gamma{(N + \gamma_{\pi1} + \gamma_{\pi0})} \Gamma{(C_x + \gamma_{\pi x} -1)}}{\Gamma{(C_x + \gamma_{\pi x}) \Gamma{(N + \gamma_{\pi1}+ \gamma_{\pi0} -1)}}} $$

Eq. 46

$$\frac{C_{x} +  \gamma_{\pi x}}{N+ \gamma_{\pi1} + \gamma_{\pi0} -1} $$

The paper says Eq.45 simplifies to Eq. 46 by using the fact that $$ \Gamma{(a + 1)} = a\Gamma(a) $$

However when I apply the given identity, Eq. 45 simplifies to this

$$\frac{N+ \gamma_{\pi1} + \gamma_{\pi0} -1}{C_{x} +  \gamma_{\pi x} -1} $$

The above equation and Eq.46 doesn't seem to be equivalent. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the trick is that you can write 
$$
\frac{\Gamma(C_{x}+\gamma_{\pi x}) \Gamma(N + \gamma_{\pi 1} + \gamma{\pi 0}-1)}{\Gamma(N+\gamma_{\pi 1}+\gamma_{\pi 0}) \Gamma(C_{x}+\gamma_{\pi x} -1)}
$$
which is the correct equation (45) in the paper
as

$$
\frac{(C_{x}+\gamma_{\pi x}-1)\Gamma(C_{x}+\gamma_{\pi x}-1)\Gamma(N+\gamma_{\pi 1} + \gamma_{\pi 0} - 1)}{(N+\gamma_{\pi 1}+\gamma_{\pi 0}-1)\Gamma(N+\gamma_{\pi 1}+\gamma_{\pi 0}-1)\Gamma(C_{x}+\gamma_{\pi x} -1)}
$$
This simplifies to the derire result

$$
\frac{C_{x}+\gamma_{\pi x}-1}{N+\gamma_{\pi 1}+\gamma_{\pi 0}-1}.  \quad (46)
$$

The thing is that equation 45 is the inverted fraction of what you seem to write in your question so the the result is also inverted.

Comment: Um, but that is exactly what @rpr is getting, and (apparently) not what is in the book.

Comment: @January i am going to edit the answer you are right!.

Comment: @Christos the form of equation 45 in my question is same as the one in the paper.

Comment: @rpr The form of your (45) is 1/(45) in the paper. Also you forgot a minus 1 on the enumerator of your equation (46).

Comment: Oh thats true!!! The paper version that i linked in my question is June 2010! But the version I was actually reading was of April 2010. And the equation are wrong in the April version!!!

Comment: the june 2010 version has this line in its abstract...
"Note: as of June 3, 2010 we have corrected some small errors in the original April 2010 report. " 
@christo I was scratching my head for some days with this ! thanks!

Comment: @rpr no problem at all! I am glad i was able to help you. Thanks for accepting the answer also.